# Floating Point in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm learning via Learn Python The Hard Way and I've come across:

> Notice the math seems “wrong”? There are no fractions, only whole numbers. Find out why by researching
>   what a “floating point” number is.

I've read what it is on: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

I can't figure out on how I can output floating point numbers, I've thought about using `round(3 + 3, 2)`.

Is this right?

Comment: Are you saying that the tutorial didn't make the requirement for a decimal point clear enough?

Comment: yes, That's why the tutorial is called "Learn Python The Hard Way" :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For floating point numbers you write a period after the number, and a zero (if it's a whole number).

Like this:

1.0  <---- Floating point.

1  <------- integer

That is how python interprets them.

```
if my_answer != your_question:
    print "I did not understand your question. Please rephrase it."
else:
    print "Good luck. Python is fun."
```

---

I agree with *rohit*, the 0 is not needed. Although it makes things easier for beginners.

Comment: I'm doing this example right now, this answered my question, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Passing a value to the `float()` constructor will make it a `float` if possible.

```
print float(2)
print float('4.5')
```

Use string interpolation or formatting to display them.

```
print '%.3f' % 4.53
```

Answer (score 2):

3 is an integer.

3.0 is a float.

```
>>> type(3)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(3.0)
<type 'float'>
```

round():

> Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0
>   digits). This always returns a floating point number.

So that is why in your case, 6.0 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with all of the answers above. You don't even need to put a zero after the period though.

For example:

```
In [1]: type(3)
Out[1]: <type 'int'>

In [2]: type(3.)
Out[2]: <type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Orange, read the last question in the lesson, the author gave you the answer

Why does / (divide) round down?
It's not really rounding down; it's just dropping the fractional part after the decimal. Try doing 7.0 / 4.0 and compare it to 7 / 4 and you'll see the difference.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Any number with a decimal is a floating point number.

In python take the following example,

If you divide 11/4 the output will be 2 [here 11 is not a floating point number]

But if you divide 11.0/4, the output will be 2.75 [here 11.0 is a floating point number].

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVpkb.png)

Answer (score 0):

python console
print(3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6)
I get 7
but in pycharm I get
6.75.

Comment: Python 2 will give you 7. Python 3 will give you 6.75. Try `7 / 2` in both version of Python to see the difference.